# RecyclerView is not syncing the new loaded images

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

my recyclerView having some issues when am reloading (fetching data ) everything is syncing with the new data  but not the images which is inside ViewPager

**onBindViewHolder**:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolderImpl(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<Information> adapter, final int i) {

    final Information current = finalContent.get(i);


    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).DESCRIPTION.setText(current.description);
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).IMAGEEXISTENCE.setText(current.imageExistence.toString());

    Log.d("TAG1","IMAGEEXISTENCE : "+((ViewHolder) viewHolder).IMAGEEXISTENCE.getText() +" position : "+i+" link : "+current.FileUrl);

   //checking if image exists if yes then set the pager size else set it to 0

    if (((ViewHolder) viewHolder).IMAGEEXISTENCE.getText().toString().matches("true")) {

  //its a string of url's combined with "|"

        String[] imgUrlArray = ((current.FileUrl.split("\\| ")));
        arrayLists.add(imgUrlArray);

        ViewPager mViewPager =  ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).viewPager;
        mViewPager.getLayoutParams().height = 550;
        mViewPager.requestLayout();


        String[] mResources = {};
        // here am passing the image url to AdapterClass
        mResources = arrayLists.get(i);
        CarouselAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CarouselAdapter(getContext(), mResources , i);
        // here am setting the pagerAdapter for my Pager
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

    } else {
           if image is not exist then am passing a blank url
        String[] imgUrlArray = new String[0];
        arrayLists.add(imgUrlArray);
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
    public class CarouselAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private String[] mResources;
    private  int mindex;

    public CarouselAdapter(Context context, String[] resources, int index) {
        mContext = context;
        mResources = resources;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mindex = index;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.carousel_imgview, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        // imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]
        // );

        if (mResources[position] == null ){

            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
//            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
//            imageView.requestLayout();

        }else {

        final DonutProgress donutProgress = (DonutProgress) itemView.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress);

            donutProgress.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,0,0,0));

            donutProgress.setUnfinishedStrokeColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            donutProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(Color.GRAY);

            donutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();


            String newUrl = mResources[position].replaceAll(" ", "");

            // for clearing cache
            DiskCacheUtils.removeFromCache(newUrl, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiskCache());



            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisk(true).build();

            imageLoader.displayImage(newUrl, imageView , options , new ImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                    donutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                    donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                    donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

                    Log.d("TAG","onLoadingCancelled");
                }
            }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {

                    donutProgress.setMax(total);
                    donutProgress.setProgress(current);

                }
            });



        }

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

}
```

i'm checking the url by printing the url and images existence (Boolean ) which is totally correct  just dont know why my recyclerView is not syncing the new images

instead the index of images is getting changed (before reloading data  image2 is on index 2) after reloading the data (and if data is new ) then all my image's index got changed if before reloading image2 was on index 2 after reloading ,  the image2 moved to index 1 it happens with all the images i dont have any clue why is this happening if anybody knows then please do guide me on how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

in

```
onBindViewHolderImpl();
```

Comment: isn't going to make a problem ? because views are no more  recyclable, it means more work less efficiency . correct me if am wrong

Comment: even trying your solution didn't make any changes

Comment: it is less efficient, but since there is if else in the bindViewHolder(), i thought it might be causing the issue. I guess it is in the class where you are updating the data of Class `Information`. How is it exactly are you updating the data and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: How are you updating new data in the recyclerViewAdapter. Where are you using `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: nowhere am not using it , is it the cause of error ? all the strings are updated correctly though

Comment: Can you comment the class where you are using recyclerView and setting the the adapter for it?